# I don't see 'path' under environment vaariables

Tags: windows-8, python, environment-variables

I am trying to set path for Python but I have no 'path' under environment variables. Below is a [link for the original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415318/) as well a screen shot.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/i8z8y8wcv/]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you trying to execute the variable?

Comment: Do you mean to CD python?

Comment: Because Idle has limited functions and I am trying to use NotePad++ and i need this to configure python to run outside of Idle.

Comment: There should be a path variable right above the two "temp" variable but for some reason i don't have that path variable. If i just knew how to get the path variable i think i would be good to go.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you just want it so that wherever you type "python" on the command line, it'll run `c:\python34\python.exe`?

Comment: open CMD and type "set". Is "Path" listed there?

Comment: @Watnaut, after typing 'set' in cmd, Path is not listed there. I have "pathext = .com; .exe; .bat....etc.

Comment: @ernie, Yes. I pretty much need to run python outside of IDLE.

Comment: The variables are listed in alphabetical order by name. `PATH` should be just a few notches above `PSModulePath`, so scroll that window up a few clicks. Or, create a **New** user variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a variable, not a command. Simply opening CMD and typing "python" will do nothing because CMD has no idea what you want to do with "python". Supply a command and the environment variable path should work.

Example: CD python

Comment: Thank you for the answer. can please explain how i can do this. I am new to this. Thank you again.

Comment: You want to make a command? Way out of my league. Maybe if you could give us more info WHY you want python included in your paths, we can give better instructions.

Comment: This guy better explains it them me...skip to 3:27

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=cpPG0bKHYKc